# Variation on Hamiltonian path problems

Tags: algorithm

Thinking about if we modify the definition of Hamiltonian path as we need to go through every edge once,but can pass vertex any times,is there still an algorithm available?
How should I modify the original Hamiltonian algorithm to account for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing a [Eulerian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path). You can find such paths with [Fleury's algorithm](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Euler_tour#Fleury.27s_algorithm).